# How can I keep the title bar showing in Fedora (Cinnamon desktop) when a window is maximized?

Tags: fedora, cinnamon

I tried Fedora the other day and one thing which really annoyed me is how the title bar on windows disappears when I maximize them. I am using the Cinnamon desktop.

How can I make it so the title bar does not disappear? I have found some answers for Gnome but not for Cinnamon.